# Voxeet API for Chat Application in IONIC 3

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, chat

Hello I wanna make an application with IONIC 3 , the app is for a audio and video call using Voxeet API

I didn't found how use Voxeet in IONIC

I need help

there are a 3 demo for voxeet but just 'ANDROID' 'IOS' 'JS'

I tried to use 'JS' demo code but no way

Comment: Did you try to search for angular/typescript usage of this API?

Comment: yeah but I didn't found it :/

Answer (score 0):

there is cordova library aclled `voxeet-cordova-conferencekit` using that you can achive that

> https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-cordova-conferencekit

Comment: Thank you , but the problem is not supported with Ionic !

Comment: send me your phone number or your facebook please and we will talk there please

Comment: go through this https://github.com/voxeet/voxeet-cordova-conferencekit/blob/master/SAMPLE_ANDROID.md